# Как сдвинуть виджет на несколько px?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, плагин

Есть WP сайт: https://transscreen.ru/

Пробую двигать смещённый виджет, чтоб он в створе встал с другими виджетами в колонке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В инспекторе меняю значения, но весь столбец с виджетами улетает.

не помогает:

```
position: absolute !important;
left: 50px;
```

Comment: Если внутри `#block-6` на `.widget_text` повесить `padding: 0`, то все будет ок.

Comment: @Simon Добавил вот так и встало в створ, но колонка виджетов резко сжалась (узкая стала) скрин: https://imgur.com/a/LMNfrwj

Comment: Ну я там айдишник `#block-6` не просто так указал, так как убирая паддинги глобально, Вы их убираете и с виджета который ниже и он без отступа упрется в левую границу. А Вы вообще в курсе что у Вас ширина колонки в которой располагаются эти виджеты `210px`, а ширина самих виджетов `241px`.

Comment: спасибо разобрался.